# gcc shared library linked incorrect in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, shared-libraries

> ```
> cat /etc/issue
> Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
>
> gcc --version
> gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
> ```

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC -c $(INCLUDES)
OFLAGS = -g -O2 -shared -Wall $(LIBS) -Wl,-soname,$(TARGET_NAME)
```

A cpp so, When I linked the so over, the dependency libs do not appear in ldd result. It's OK in CentOS6.3. the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set OK because the ELF executable file I made is OK.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking for help with something? Or are you trying to [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)?

Comment: there may be some options with gcc. I don't know if it is a bug.